# Using linkedlist in method gives 'cannot be resolved' error, java

Tags: java

I have the following `snake.snakeMove(dots, leftDirection, rightDirection, upDirection, downDirection, DOT_SIZE);` in Board.java in which i have intialized snake using `private SnakeLinkedList snake = new SnakeLinkedList();`. In my SnakeLinkedList class however, the snakeMove method gives me the error `snake cannot be resolved` .

```
public void snakeMove(int dots, boolean left, boolean right, boolean up, boolean down, final int SIZE) {



     for (int z = dots; z >0; z--) {
       snake.getJoint(z).setX(snake.getJoint(z-1).getX());
     }

     if(left) {
       snake.getHead().setX(snake.getHead().getX() - SIZE);
     }

     if(right) {
       snake.getHead().setX(snake.getHead().getX() + SIZE);
     }

     if(up) {
       snake.getHead().setY(snake.getHead().getY() - SIZE);
     }

     if(down) {
       snake.getHead().setY(snake.getHead().getY() + SIZE);
     }
 }
```

how can i access snake or do the operation on the snake linkedlist without having the error to occur?

SnakeLinkedList.java :

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;

public class SnakeLinkedList {
SnakeNode head = null;

public void addHead(int x, int y, Color c) {
head = new SnakeNode(x, y, c);
}

public void addJoint(int x, int y, Color c) {
SnakeNode newJoint = new SnakeNode(x, y, c);
newJoint.setNext(head.getNext());
head.setNext(newJoint);
}

public void addTail(Color c) {
SnakeNode curr = head;
while (curr.getNext() != null) {
curr = curr.getNext();
}
SnakeNode newJoint = new SnakeNode(curr.getX() + 10, curr.getY() + 10, c);
curr.setNext(newJoint);
}

public SnakeNode getHead() {
return head;
}

public SnakeNode getJoint(int i) {
SnakeNode curr = head;
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
  curr = curr.getNext();
}
return curr;
}


public void addFirst(SnakeNode node) {
node.setNext(head);
head = node;
}

public void addLast(SnakeNode node) {
if (head == null) {
  head = node;
  return;
}

SnakeNode curr = head;
while (curr.getNext() != null) {
  curr = curr.getNext();
}
curr.setNext(node);
}

public void snakeMove(int dots, boolean left, boolean right, boolean up, 
boolean down, final int SIZE) {

     for (int z = dots; z >0; z--) {
       this.getJoint(z).setX(this.getJoint(z-1).getX());
     }

     if(left) {
       this.getHead().setX(this.getHead().getX() - SIZE);
     }

     if(right) {
       this.getHead().setX(this.getHead().getX() + SIZE);
     }

     if(up) {
       this.getHead().setY(this.getHead().getY() - SIZE);
     }

     if(down) {
       this.getHead().setY(this.getHead().getY() + SIZE);
     }
 }
```

}

My SnakeNode.java class:

```
package com.zetcode;
import java.awt.Color;

public class SnakeNode {

private int x;
private int y;
private Color c;
private SnakeNode next;

public SnakeNode() {
next = null;
}

public SnakeNode(int x, int y, Color c) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.c = c;
}

public int getX() {
return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
this.y = y;
}

public Color getColor() {
return c;
} 

public void setColor(Color c) {
this.c = c;
}

public SnakeNode getNext() {
return next;
}

public void setNext(SnakeNode next) {
this.next = next;
}
}
```

SNIPPETS OF RELATED CODE FROM BOARD.JAVA:

```
  private SnakeLinkedList snake = new SnakeLinkedList();
 private Color[] colours = {Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN};



 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (inGame) {

        checkApple();
        checkCollision();
        snake.snakeMove(dots, leftDirection, rightDirection, upDirection, downDirection, DOT_SIZE);
        //move();
    }

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: where you declare the `SnakeLinkedList` object, It's the same class that the method in?

Comment: Can you share the full code snippet which is causing this? It is not very evident from the question that where you have declared these methods and what modifiers you have used with these variables.

Comment: no, the method is in a different class, namely board.java @sc0der

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary the reason I cannot put the whole code in it is because the method is in the SnakeLinkedList class and the initializing for snake is done in another class named board.java in which the method is called.

Comment: @theCelestials you can access by the class name if it's static or by instance if the list not static

Comment: @sc0der how do i create an instance of the list in another class?

Comment: Could you put the code of another class

Comment: @sc0der alright so i think my question is a bit confusing, i'll explain. So the SnakeLinkedList.java class has the snakeMove method. In another class, Board.java,  I have declared a new SnakeLinkedList called snake. In board.java I use snake.snakeMove(parameters). in my snakeMove method, using snake gives me error saying "snake cannot be resolved".

Comment: @sc0der the code in board.java, is 'private SnakeLinkedList snake = new SnakeLinkedList();
    private Color[] colours = {Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN};'

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (inGame) {

            checkApple();
            checkCollision();
            snake.snakeMove(dots, leftDirection, rightDirection, upDirection, downDirection, DOT_SIZE);
            //move();
        }

        repaint();
    }

Comment: Hmmm, let's see that

Comment: I have posted a solution, could this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the list using `head` from `getHead()` method in `SnakeLinkedList`, And make sure the head is assigned before usage I mean `addHead()` method has been called.

Also, I added check `if (head == null) return;` in `snakeMove()` to make sure the head not null

like this

```
public void snakeMove(int dots, boolean left, boolean right, boolean up, boolean down, final int SIZE) {
     if (head == null) return;
     for (int z = dots; z >0; z--) {
       getJoint(z).setX(snake.getJoint(z-1).getX());
     }

     if(left) {
       getHead().setX(snake.getHead().getX() - SIZE);
     }

     if(right) {
       getHead().setX(snake.getHead().getX() + SIZE);
     }

     if(up) {
       getHead().setY(snake.getHead().getY() - SIZE);
     }

     if(down) {
       getHead().setY(snake.getHead().getY() + SIZE);
     }
 }
```

, And update

```
public SnakeNode getJoint(int i) {
SnakeNode curr = head;
for (int k = 0; k < i && curr !=null ; k++) {
  curr = curr.getNext();
}
return curr;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213657/discussion-on-answer-by-sc0der-using-linkedlist-in-method-gives-cannot-be-resol).